# What difference is there in chanting/reciting in the same way as monks?

Tags: chanting, chant, recitation

Recitals or chants such as `Om Mani Padme Hum` by monks have [particular tones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG_lNuNUVd4).

Is there a difference in the ability or inability to chant in a same way for individuals that are not monastic?

Comment: Practice practice practice.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing about being a monastic that inherently changes your vocal  timbre or range.

If you listen to dharanis, sutras, mantras, etc., being chanted by Chinese, Thai, Japanese, or most other monks, their voices sound like anyone else's. Many of the Tibetan chanting recordings you'll find online come from specific groups that either have training in throat singing or overtone singing, or are otherwise carefully selected to sound good on a recording.